# SQL datatype for using a string sentence

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes

I want to create a SQL Server stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspGetCharacterID                             
   (@characterName vchar(1000)) 
as            
   SELECT c.charatcer_full    
   FROM CHARACTER c (nolock)      
   WHERE character_full IN (@characterName)      
   ORDER BY C.characterID
```

From code, `@charactername` I am passing --> `'Batman in latest movies', 'Superman in latest movies'`

But in code its returning zero rows.

NOTE: if I run the same select query in SQL with those string, it successfully returns two rows.

**QUESTION**: which datatype should be used, so that requirement is satisfied?

`'Varchar'` and `'Text'` didn't work.

Please guide

Thanks

Comment: Will this string represent data in single record *Batman in latest movies, Superman in latest movies*

Comment: The tabele 'Character', 'Batman in latest movies' has 1 row and 'Superman in latest movies' has 1 row. So running the above query returns two rows.

Comment: It's not a question of the datatype - the point is, you cannot do this they way you're doing it. You cannot pass in a list of strings as a `varchar` and then used those in a `.. IN (....)` construct. Doesn't work that way. See [this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866577/passing-delimited-string-to-stored-procedure-to-search-database) that deals with this issue, and see the answer provided by `KM.` - that's the way to do it

Comment: @marc_s --  So how would I pass more than one string in 'IN' clause using Stored Proc ? And why the Select query mentioned above, runs succesfully when run manually with those list of strings ?

Comment: @Kings. [see that other SO question I linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866577/passing-delimited-string-to-stored-procedure-to-search-database) - the answer provided there shows you how to do this!

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TYPE tp_names AS
        TABLE
        (
        name VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL
        )

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE
        uspGetCharacterID (@names tp_names READONLY)
AS
        SELECT  c.character_full    
        FROM    CHARACTER c
        WHERE   character_full IN
                (
                SELECT  name
                FROM    @names
                )
        ORDER BY
                characterID

GO

DECLARE @names tp_names

INSERT
INTO    @names
VALUES
        ('Batman in latest movies'),
        ('Superman in latest movies')

EXEC    uspGetCharacterID
                @names = @names
```